# member of www-data but it doesn't show in groups

Tags: permissions, group

When I look at the groups that user 'wim' is a member of, `www-data` group does not show.
When I look at the members of `www-data`, user `wim` is listed.

```
$ groups
wim adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
$ members wim
wim
$ members www-data
www-data wim
```

When trying to rename a file that is owned by `www-data` with 764 file permissions as user `wim` I get a 'permission denied' message.

```
$ ls -la htmlKauPriceListSingleProductGTS.inc 
-rwxrw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 3440  2月 12 14:46 htmlKauPriceListSingleProductGTS.inc
$ mv htmlKauPriceListSingleProductGTS.inc ZZZhtmlKauPriceListSingleProductGTS.inc
mv: cannot move 'htmlKauPriceListSingleProductGTS.inc' to 'ZZZhtmlKauPriceListSingleProductGTS.inc': Permission denied
```

Could someone please explain why user `wim` is in the group `www-data` but doesn't have the permissions to rename a file that is in the `www-data` group?
And what I have to do to give user `wim` the necessary permissions to edit files in the `www-data` group?

thank you

Comment: If you have not logged out or restarted your system, try do it. A re-login would be enough Specially if you are working directly on terminal just log in or you can use `su - your_user` to be able to login having the new group

Comment: About `permission denied` when you try to rename, the file permissions are not related to file but the parent directory, in this case **include** dir: `/var/www/html/genkigenki06/publicHtml/include` So make sure you have write permissions (`rwx` perms)  in group section.

Comment: Edgar Magallon's answer solve my problem. I have been out of IT for a while now but I could have sworn that I could do similar things a few years back without having to restart.

Comment: You need to logout/login. On the kernel level, group memberships are a property of the _process_, **not** the _user_, even though they're defined per-user in the user database. So to get a new group membership active, you need to arrange for something to start a new process for you, with those groups. Or in practice, to start a new login, which is the point where the per-user group memberships are checked. (Logging out existing sessions shouldn't be needed, they just won't get the new group ids.)

Answer (score 2):

Permission to create a file (used by the `mv` command), is given by the directory. You have not shown the mode of the directory, so we can not say more on this.

Adding a user to a group, just changes a file (`/etc/groups`).
I process inherits groups from its parent, or is given groups by the login process (the login process has extra privileges to do this, and reads them from `/etc/groups`).

To get your shell to be a member of the new group, you can:

- Reboot
- Logout and back in again
- Use the `newgrp` command, to start a new shell. (this only affects child processes)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my system solved this problem.